# xml schema to validate unordered elements of xml document

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I am writing a xml schema for validating a xml document. I stuck with defining some complexType content for some unordered elements of xml data.

The xml data appears like below:

```
<country name="India">
    <state name="Karnataka">
        <!-- about state -->
        <capital>Bangalore</capital>
        <largestCity>Bangalore</largestCity>
        <districts>30</districts>
        <population>61130704</population>
        <language>Kannada</language>

        <!-- cities in state -->
        <city name="Bijapur">
            <talukas>30</talukas>
            <population>611307</population>
        </city>
        <city name="Belgaum">
                <talukas>30</talukas>
                <population>6113070</population>
        </city>

        <!-- cities will be listed here -->
    </state>

    <state name="Maharashtra">
        <!-- about state -->
        <largestCity>Mumbai</largestCity>
        <capital>Mumbai</capital>
        <population>112372972</population>
        <language>Marathi</language>
        <districts>35</districts>

        <!-- cities in state -->
        <!-- cities will be listed here -->

    </state>
</country>
```

As shown in above xml data, the first five elements under each 'state' tag can appear in 
any order.

Could somebody please help me to write xml schema defination for such kind of inputs.
I tried to write some thing like this:

```
<xs:group name="stateElements">
      <xs:all>
         <xs:element name="capital" type="xs:string"/>
          ....
   <xs:all>
</xs:group>
<xs:element name="state">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="stateElements"/>
         <xs:element name="city" type="cityType" maxOccurs="unbound"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   <xs:complexType>
<xs:element>
```

This is not working.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to wrap all your <city/> elements in something called <cities/>, with a maximum occurrence of 1. Drop the group, and have your complex type describing the content model for <state/> be an <xsd:all/>.

The limitation you have to work around is that any particle under an <xsd:all/> compositor must not repeat (maxOccurs="1").

Comment: Thank you Petru Gardea, can't I use any mixed models <xsd:all> and <xsd:choice> together..

Comment: Unfortunately, no, xsd:all is very picky, when it comes to many things. I know it is a dry reading, but it is the best source: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Model_Groups, section 3.8.6; then look around for more on xsd:all, on the same page.